# Rejected push, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: json, heroku, git-commit, git-push

I have an `Angular 2` project which I intend to deploy to Heroko, so I configured the `package.json` file, and created a `server.js` file in the project's root, and when I'm trying to push the project, it gives me a `parse error` and says that it expected another key-value pair at line 13, column 3. I've verified the respective line 13, column 3 in the file, but I don't find anything strange there. Maybe I do not see something =/. Below I'll leave the 'package.json', and a screen with the error message.

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "game2048",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  },
  "engines": {
        "node": "8.9.4",
        "npm": "5.6.0",
  }
}
```

> The error message

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON file is malformed. You might want to use a JSON validator to check it: https://jsonlint.com/

Remove the , at the end of `"postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod",` and `"npm": "5.6.0",`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, I just didn't notice that i left the comma in those places...

Comment: I also do that sometimes... thinking it's JavaScript. xD

Comment: Same story, in my case the problem is also that it's my first time working with JSON xD

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you shoud try to `npm cache clean` and re-install your package.

Comment: I tried this just now, and the result is the same (( .